# how to add an image on a another blurry image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add an image on top of another image, but I want the background image to be blurry and the second to be normal

```css
header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60)), url(img.jpg);
  height: 85vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  filter: blur(8px);
}

img {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="img.jpg" alt="img">
</header>
```

Comment: You can't blur a background image..only actual elements. In this case, I'd use a psuedo-element.

Comment: and the reason of this ? only the upper image will be visible ... can you be more clear on what you want

Comment: can you provide demo link

Comment: I already fixed it. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:before` pseudo class for the blurred background and **Flexbox** for the center align of image

***Stack Snippet***

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  height: 85vh;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

header:before {
  content: "";
  filter: blur(8px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/general-night-golden-gate-bridge-hd-wallpapers-golden-gate-bridge-wallpaper.jpg);
  z-index: -1;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="img">
</header>
```